# Getting Null Pointer exception in spark UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have code as below. I am using spark UDF to add new column called "IssueDate" to the existing data frame but getting null pointer exception. So any advise/suggestion on this to get rid of this issue.

```
    class IssueDateDateHandler(var masterDF) extends Serializable {
      val getIssueDate:(String)=> Option[String] = {(Id) =>
        Option(Id) match {
          case Some(Id) => {
            val matchingIdDF = masterDF.where(col("Id") === Id)
            val issueDt = matchingIdDF.select("IssueDate").head().mkString
            Option(issueDt)
          }
          case _ => Some("")
        }
      }

      val issueDate = udf[Option[String], String](getIssueDate)

      def addIssueDate(transformedDFs: MutableList[DataFrame]): MutableList[DataFrame] = {
          for (tmpDF <- transformedDFs) {
               val df = tmpDF.withColumn("IssueDate", issueDate(col("Id")))
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Exception is:   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:182)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:64)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedPlan(Dataset.scala:3411)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1484)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.where(Dataset.scala:1512)
 at com.jetblue.revenueingest.transformations.IssueDateHandler$$anonfun$2.apply(IssueDateHandler.scala:28)
 at com.jetblue.revenueingest.transformations.IssueDateHandler$$anonfun$2.apply(IssueDateHandler.scala:25)
 ... 21 more

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding a comment.

Comment: please add the error log

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR check if there is a case where the masterDF coming from class definition is null**

In your user-defined function you have two inputs:

- `Id`, which is the argument of your user-defined function
- `masterDF`, which come from the class where the user-defined function is defined

So what happens if one of those two inputs is null ?

#### Id is null

If `Id` is null, then `Option(Id)` at first line of the user-defined function is `None`, so the pattern matching in the same line goes to `case _:` that returns `Some("")`

So there is no way that a null `Id` results to a `NullPointerException`

#### masterDF is null

If `Id` is not null, the pattern matching goes to `case Some(Id):` which execute the following line:

```scala
val matchingIdDF = masterDF.where(col("Id") === Id)
```

As `masterDF` is null, we try to call the method `where` on a null `DataFrame`, resulting to a `NullPointerException`

#### Conlusion

This user-defined function will throw `NullPointerException` only when `masterDF` is null